# Laravel Custom Request Is not woring

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-formrequest

So I was trying to use Laravel custom request, following the documentation:

`api.php`

```
Route::post('/register-user', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

`AuthController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\TestRequest;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class AuthController extends BaseController
{
  /**
   * Register a new user
   * @param TestRequest $request
   * @return void
   */
  public function register(TestRequest $request): array
  {
    dd($request);
  }
}
```

`TestRequest.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array<string, mixed>
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      'name' => 'required|string',
    ];
  }
}
```

When I make a POST request to this route, my `$request` object is just all empty.
As you can see: [image]

But when I change the TestRequest to just a regular Request, it works normally.

What am I missing using my custom TestRequest?

Comment: What are you using to request? browser, POSTMAN? check my answer, your `$request` need to have the `method: "POST"`

Comment: I'm sure I'm sending a POST request

Answer (score 1):

Form requests are custom request classes that encapsulate their own validation and authorization logic. The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called.

If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display.

If you want to retrieve the validated input data, you can use :

```
$validated = $request->validated();
```

I hope this can help

```
/**
  * Register a new user
  * @param TestRequest $request
  * @return void
  */
public function register(TestRequest $request): array
{
    // The incoming request is valid...
 
    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // Store data...
    
}
```

Comment: `{
 "message": "Call to a member function validated() on null",
 "exception": "Error",
 "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php",
 "line": 225,
 "trace": [
  {
   "file": "/var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php",
   "line": 17,
   "function": "validated",
   "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest",
   "type": "->"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

The method you have on the print is `GET`, and your route in `api.php` is `POST`.

Comment: I don't get why it says its a GET request. 
As you can see it's all empty, and also if I just change TestRequest to Request, it works normaly.